# fputcsv and fgetcsv

Tags: php, fgetcsv, fputcsv

My code looks like this .. the o/p is a csv file with 4 values in ONE cell and so on in the FIRST column alone

Better versions of this code please . ASAP

```
foreach ($xml->xyz as $xyz) {  
$f = fopen('blahblahblah.csv', 'a') or die("can't open file");  
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($lis),';','"');
```

Comment: `Better versions of this code please . ASAP` You must be kidding?

Comment: you should definitely defuse that "better versions" bit, it sounds very rude (Which I assume is not the intention.)

Comment: Well iteration of your foreach loop, you're opening the same file and overwriting the content... assuming that it will let you open that file a second time, because you're never closing it... and for good measure, your snippet doesn't even have the closing } for the loop, so you should be getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$f = fopen('blahblahblah.csv', 'a') or die("can't open file");    
foreach ($xml->xyz as $xyz) fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($lis),';','"');
fclose($f);
```

It should be fine like this.